Help me find this really old comedy movie with a mime
I'll try my best not to be vague about this, but as I found this site I thought that this may be the place to find out what is this movie that has been bugging me for ages.
Here are my few memories about it:

I know that this movie looks really old (at least in my head, something from the 60/70s) because it old, washed off, colors.
It seems to me that it was about a wacky group of people where each one had a kind of ability. Although I only remember two of them from the scene I recall with these two guys:

a mime
a guy with a taxi horn

I remember these two being chased by another group of people.
The guy with the taxi horn stuns a part of the group of chasers with a really loud sound of the horn.
Meanwhile, the mime makes an invisible wall which all of chasers hit while following him. And I'm almost certain he then mimics as if he was opening the door in the invisible wall to get to the other side.

Well, that's all I remember. Sorry if it isn't much.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

@Paulie_D Well, I gave it a shot. Its a very old childhood memory. I unfortunately can't remember more than that.

So language and color...surely you remember that much? It's amazing how much you can recall if you put your mind to it.

@Paulie_D Believe me. This movie has been bugging me for years now. The problem is I was a child, so most of the movies I watched were dubbed to my language (portuguese). And as I said, I figure it was something from the 60/70s. It had those old washed off colors.

I am thinking you mean "a mime" rather than a mimic? A mimic imitates or takes on the role of something. A mime is a specialized form of theatre where one is silent and acts out a story through body gestures, and pretending to interact with imaginary objects.

@Yorik Yes. You are correct. I forgot that this difference exists.
